# Append to a File with fstream Instead of Overwriting

Tags: c++, file, overwrite

I'm trying to create a basic highscore system for a project I'm working on.

The problem I'm having is, although I write the names into my main they just overwrite the previous.

Currently I have this:

```
void ManagePoint::saveScore(string Name, int Score)
{

    ofstream newFile("scorefile.txt");

    if(newFile.is_open())   
    {
        newFile << Name << " " << Score;            
    }
    else 
    {
        //You're in trouble now Mr!
    }


    newFile.close();

}
```

and for testing I'm adding them like so:

```
runner->saveScore("Robert", 34322);

runner->saveScore("Paul", 526);

runner->saveScore("Maxim", 34322);
```

On load display all that will appear is Maxim's score, how can I loop through and save them all, or append all or something?

Comment: Have a look at some options via [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to open the file with the append mode:

```
ofstream newFile("scorefile.txt", std::ios_base::app);
```

There are [various other modes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream) too.

Comment: Ah that got it, they've all saved now. Still have a problem with my loading and displaying though. Baby steps. :) Thanks.