# Learning about file input and output, I'm able to write to file but I can't print from file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a simple file input and output program called employee list. It creates the list and stores the names and the salaries of the employees entered in a list.

The first problem I have is, anytime I run the code, it just replaces the list instead of adding to it.

My second problem is printing from the file to the console, It just prints a negative integer.

```c++
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

  std::string First_Name;
  std::string Last_Name;
  std::string NAMES;
  int SALARY;
  int Employee_Salary;

  std::fstream Employee_List("employee list.txt",
                             std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::app);

  std::cout << std::left << std::endl;

  if (!Employee_List) {

    std::cout << "File not Found" << std::endl;
    return -1;
  } else {

    Employee_List << "*************Employee Names and Salary***************"
                  << std::endl;
    Employee_List << "Names" << std::setw(25) << "Salary" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Please Enter First Name" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> First_Name;

    std::cout << "Please Enter Last Name" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> Last_Name;

    std::cout << "Please Enter Salary" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> SALARY;

    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;
    Employee_List << First_Name << " " << Last_Name << "," << std::setw(18)
                  << SALARY << std::endl;

    Employee_List.ignore(255, '\n');

    std::getline(Employee_List, NAMES, ',');
    Employee_List >> Employee_Salary;
    std::cout << std::setw(20) << NAMES << Employee_Salary << std::endl;

    while (!Employee_List.eof()) {

      std::cout << std::setw(20) << NAMES << Employee_Salary << std::endl;

      std::getline(Employee_List, NAMES, ',');
      Employee_List >> Employee_Salary;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: See [why `eof` in a loop condition is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/9254539).

Comment: Why are you trying to read from the file and write to the file **at the same time**? Open the file for output first, write to the file, then when you have finished writing, close the file, reopen the file for input and only then start reading from it.

Comment: it is rare that you want to open a text file for reading and writing because text data is almost never the same size for each record making it extremely hard to edit a record without either leaving crap in the file or accidentally overwriting the next record. It is iorders of magnitude easier to read the file, edit in memory, then overwrite the file with the edited copy in memory.

Comment: You don't need the `else { }`. Remove it to save some indentation!

Comment: You are already using the `string` container, so you might as well create a `struct` holding the data for each person (e.g. name, salary, etc..) and then create a `vector` of `struct` allowing you to open the file for reading, read all data into your vector of struct, close the input stream, manipulate the data with your program as needed, and then before you exit, open the file for writing (replacing the input file completely), and write the vector of struct out to your file.

Comment: besides, ALL CAPS are reserved for macros (and sometimes constants)

Comment: Thanks, all of your insights were really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue. (1st Issue) What you are currently doing is *replacing* the file contents every time you write something to it. What you want to be doing is appending to the file. Check out this link:

[Append to a File with fstream Instead of Overwriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056406/append-to-a-file-with-fstream-instead-of-overwriting)